# Xcode Swift: How to play audio when user receives local notification in background

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uilocalnotification, alarm

Hello I am making an alarm app and I am trying to play audio when the user receives the local notification. I keep all my local notification functions and management in a swift file titled NotificationPublisher. It works when the user has the app in the foreground because the willPresent() function gets called, however I am trying to make it work in the background/phone is closed.

Is there a function that gets called when a local notification is presented in background and not just the foreground?

If not am I tackling this feature wrong.

Here is my sendNotification function where I take in my alarms and schedule the local notifications. (In my NotificationPublisher.swift)

```
func sendNotification(alarm : Alarm, badge: Int?) {

    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = alarm.alarmName
    notificationContent.subtitle = alarm.alarmTime + " " + alarm.alarmPeriod
    notificationContent.body = "Click here to open the app and click the solve button!"

    if let badge = badge {
        var currentBadgeCount = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
        currentBadgeCount += badge
        notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(integerLiteral: currentBadgeCount)
    }

    notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    var hour = ""
    if(alarm.alarmTime.count == 4){
        hour = String(alarm.alarmTime.prefix(1))
    } else {
        hour = String(alarm.alarmTime.prefix(2))
    }

    let minute = String(alarm.alarmTime.suffix(2))

    var intHour = Int(hour)!

    if(alarm.alarmPeriod == "PM" && intHour != 12){
        intHour += 12
    } else if(alarm.alarmPeriod  == "AM" && intHour == 12) {
        intHour = 0
    }

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    if(alarm.alarmDays.filter{$0}.count == 0) {
        dateComponents.hour = intHour
        dateComponents.minute = Int(minute)!
        dateComponents.timeZone = .current

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true) // Repeating Alarm
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: alarm.alarmKey, content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger) // replace trigger with delaytimetrigger and vice versa for exact time

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    } else {
        dateComponents.hour = intHour
        dateComponents.minute = Int(minute)!
        dateComponents.timeZone = .current

        let days = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"]
        for i in alarm.alarmDays.enumerated() {
            if(i.element){
                dateComponents.weekday = i.offset + 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: alarm.alarmKey + days[i.offset], content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the audio function that is in my ViewController.swift that I am calling from my willPresent() function.

```
func alarmSound() {
    print("alarm sound was called")

    if let player = player, player.isPlaying {
        player.stop()
    } else {
        let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "buzzer", ofType: "mp3")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

            guard let urlString = urlString else { return }

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString))

            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.numberOfLoops = -1
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer for this question is no, in iOS you can't play sounds from your app while it is in background mode.

Comment: @JanCássio So how do Alarm apps such as Alarmy work? I got an alarm sound while it was in the background and my phone was locked

Comment: Search for 'Swift run app background.'

Comment: @sayad ok I got it. First of all, sorry about that, I misunderstood your question. Ok yes, you can play a sound while your app is in background. Check if you enabled background mode properly. Here's the relevant info (is a WatchKit article but works for iOS) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_support/playing_background_audio

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work, but I know the setting sound property will change the sound for your notification. Please check the below link and share your feedback.

[https://smashswift.com/create-custom-notification-sound/#:~:text=Scheduling%20local%20notification%20you%20need,of%20UNNotificationSound%20to%20sound%20field.&text=The%20filename%20has%20to%20match,the%20same%20with%20Push%20Notification](https://smashswift.com/create-custom-notification-sound/#:%7E:text=Scheduling%20local%20notification%20you%20need,of%20UNNotificationSound%20to%20sound%20field.&text=The%20filename%20has%20to%20match,the%20same%20with%20Push%20Notification).